# Refresh DataGridViewTextBoxColumn when user clicked DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

Assume i have **DataGrid** below:

[image: DataGrid]

The first column is **DataGridViewComboBoxColumn**. Example when the user click one of the Product from the **ComboBox**, I want the column **DataGridViewTextBoxColumn** which is column **Price** to be refreshed or updated triggered by the selection change of the ComboBox.

Below is my code for a normal TextBox. How do i refresh a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn?

```
Private Sub refresh_grid(ByVal productOrder As String)
        Dim mysql As String = "SELECT FLD_PRODUCT_PRICE FROM TBL_PRODUCTS "
        Dim mydatatable As New DataTable
        Dim myreader As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(mysql, myconnection)
        myreader.Fill(mydatatable)

        Price = mydatatable.Rows(0).Item("FLD_PRODUCT_PRICE")

    End Sub
```

Comment: `DataGridView.CellValueChanged Event` [From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataGridView.CellValueChanged` for this

```
'This is your function for getting a Price based on product
'Use your returned type of Price value
Private Function GetPrice(selectedProduct As String) As Decimal 
    Dim mysql As String = "SELECT FLD_PRODUCT_PRICE FROM TBL_PRODUCTS "
    Dim mydatatable As New DataTable
    Dim myreader As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(mysql, myconnection)
    myreader.Fill(mydatatable)

    Return mydatatable.Rows(0).Item("FLD_PRODUCT_PRICE")
End Function

Private Sub DataGridView_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    if e.RowIndex < 0 Then Exit Sub 'Exit if current row is Header row
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    Dim comboBoxColumnIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim textboxColumnIndex As Integer = 1
    if e.ColumnIndex = comboBoxColumnIndex Then
        'Get price and update "Price" column
        Dim product As String = dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value.ToString()
        Dim price As Decimal = Me.GetPrice(product)
        dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(textboxColumnIndex).Value = price
    End If

End Sub
```

Or you can use `DataGridView.CellEndEdit` eventhandler, which will be raised only when value was edited bu user.
You can use same code inside `CellEndEdit` eventhandler because `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` types contains `RowIndex` and `ColumnIndex` proerties too

Comment: I tried but still it won't update the price column when i change the selected product?

Comment: Consider my code as "pseudo code" which is very close to the `vb.net`.  Check if eventhandler wired to event. Add "Handle" to the line `Private Sub DataGridView_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles YourDataGridView.CellValueChanged`. If not working then debug line byline and check if event raised properly and code is executed

Comment: Okay my bad. I missed that. So i tried and whatever Product that i chose on column Product, it will display the same price of the first row of data in the database. Can you explain why?

Comment: You need to check method which retrieve price information from database. Current code which used in the question will always return same data, because you didn't use any condition in the sql query

Comment: I have to edit this part right?
`Return mydatatable.Rows(0).Item("FLD_PRODUCT_PRICE")` ? Wrap it with CellValueChanged ?

Comment: Try debug line by line and check from where wrong Price is coming

Comment: Could you help me out with the return function? I can't seem to find a solution